Android 12 and 13 OS - Activity Recognition With broadcast receiver in background stop giving me Recognition Results after few hours or days
I am trying to get user activity states by Activity Recognition API and it works in foreground and for few hours in background too (When user exit the app) but after more than 4/5 hours or after 2 or 3 days it stop sending user activity states by Activity Recognition API. In specific REALME 12 and Samsung M12 Android 12 versions I am facing this inconsistency from last 2 weeks. When I debug and try to catch the issue then it will trigger and give me Activity Recognition update in on start command as I mention below. I also tried with Activity-Transition method and create new Broadcast receiver still getting no result at all. In Android version 14 it is working perfect.

Also Registering SERVICE in Manifest

<service
            android:name="com.spectra.ess.service.TimeLineTrackingService"
            android:exported="false"
            android:foregroundServiceType="location" />


Permissions in Manifest

 <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION" />
and also Runtime Permission for Physical Activity given.


Setup Activity Recognition and Registering Broadcast Receiver In

public class TimeLineTrackingService extends Service {

  @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
startActivityRecognitionUpdates();
}
 private void startActivityRecognitionUpdates() {
       Intent intent = new Intent(this, TimeLineTrackingService.class);

        mActivityRecognitionPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 100, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE);


        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        mActivityRecognitionClient.requestActivityUpdates(ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION_DETECTION_INTERVAL,
                mActivityRecognitionPendingIntent);
    }
 public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
       
        if (ActivityRecognitionResult.hasResult(intent)) {
            final ActivityRecognitionResult result = ActivityRecognitionResult.extractResult(intent);
            // Run the activity detection logic in worker thread.
            mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    handleActivityRecognition(result);
                }
            });
        } 
        return START_STICKY;
    }
}



This is expected.  You can't have an app in the background constantly on Android.  You can last longer in certain circumstances (such as by having a foreground service), but nothing will keep you resident forever on Android.  And modern Android is very aggressive about killing background processes.

@GabeSechan the background service should continue running until the end day is reached. If the user clicks on the start day, then the service should automatically start in the background without any triggering event. Currently, I'm encountering an issue where ActivityRecognitionResult.hasResult(intent) stops providing results on Realme and Samsung M13 devices with OS versions 12 and 13 respectively. I've attempted to address this by implementing solutions like ActivityTransition, but it hasn't resolved the problem. Can you please suggest a solution for this issue?

That's not how background services work on Android.  They can and will be killed at any time.  You cannot rely on them running for more than about 2 minutes when your app is not in the foreground.  There are literally hundreds of questions about that on this site.

@GabeSechan Thank you for the update, but it seems there may have been a misunderstanding. Could you please review the video URL below? This will give you a better idea of what we are trying to convey.https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dKgu6VyDt0g4UtWYF3qloi7OdHztR7N3/view
ActivityRecognitionResult Method stop giving me results of motions in lower level devices Realme 12 os and samusng m13 OS version 13.

@kiranmalvi Service with START_STICKY doesn't guarantee continuous background execution instead use ForegroundService or WorkerManager.
